# $R^2$ of two regressed lines divided by each other.

Tags: statistics, regression

In this situation I have two lines. For the sake of the question I will simplify the two lines to simple linear equations. $$f(x) = x + 1$$ $$g(x) = x + 2$$

$f(x)$  and $g(x)$ were linearly regressed using least sum of squares. If the R$^2$ value of $f(x)$ is $0.5$ and the R$^2$ value of $g(x)$ is $0.7$, what is the R$^2$ value of the result of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$?

Comment: "$R^2$ (Accuracy)" - that's... really not the way to interpret it; it is merely a measure of correlation, and one should not try to read more into it than that.

Comment: What do you mean by the $R$-squared of $f(x)/g(x)$? You divided what by what?

Comment: @GFauxPas What is the R$^2$ of the equation $\frac{x + 1}{x + 2}$ knowing that the numerator and denominator both have different R$^2$ values.

Comment: @Mozzie that is not the equation of a regression line, so how can it have an $R^2$?

Comment: @GFauxPas because the equations that it is comprised of were regressed. Just because the final equation is not regressed, the components that make it are, you can not simply ignore the fact that the equations have a margin of error just because they are being divided by each other.